# Active sounding variant of "in the process"

Tags: phrase-requests

Given the sentence:

> The company is _________ of selling off many assets.

The best I could think of to replace "in the process" here was "in the midst of." It reads kind of underwhelming for my taste, and I'd like to spice it up and make it sound more active sounding or the like since I'm using it as a title.

Comment: Personally, I think the most direct is to drop the extra wording altogether: *The company is selling off many assets.* However, while titles are a matter of choice, that doesn't sound like a typical title. (Nor do any of the variations.) A typical title would be *A Company Asset Sell-Off*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[actively](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/actively)**

> ADVERB 
>  1 In a deliberate and positive way. *The company is actively looking for a buyer.*
>
> 2 In an energetic or vigorous way. *They were actively engaged in supporting the war effort*.

Thus, your sentence can become:

> The company is actively selling off many assets.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a question of style and the best answer would probably depend on what it was a title for. Still, for the particular example you give, you could use "in the course of", or "in the act of" or "in the operation of". Or you could simply say "The company is actively selling off many assets".

Comment: What exactly is it to sell something **actively**? What other way of selling is there?

Comment: @jsw29 - For comparison, consider "When I walked into the kitchen, I found my friend's preschooler enthusiastically beating imaginary cake batter in a big metal bowl with a whisk.  I decided to go back and powder my nose again."  Yes, an adverb can often be omitted, without removing the basic meaning of the sentence.  However, an adverb can add pizazz.  It can clarify the specific meaning.  "Actively selling off" is different from "quietly selling" or "gradually selling."